# Why why doesn't Mathematica know that Sqrt[f^2]=f?

Tags: series-expansion

I am using Series to do some calculations. A toy example is:

Input:

```
Series[Sqrt[Exp[h]*f^2], {h, 0, 1}]
```

Output:

```
Sqrt[f^2]+(Sqrt[f^2] h)/2+O[h]^2
```

How can I make Mathematica know that

```
Sqrt[f^2]=f
```

?

Similarly if I write:

Input:

```
Sqrt[f^2]
```

The output is:

```
Sqrt[f^2]
```

This might seem not relevant for this toy example, but for longer expressions, it becomes intractable. I tried, Simplify and FullSimplify but they did not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `Sqrt[(-1)^2]`. But look into `Refine` and use the assumption `f >= 0`.

Comment: `PowerExpand`..

Comment: FullSimplify[Sqrt[x^2], x >= 0]

Comment: See also `Surd`.

Comment: To say what has already been said in a different way, the fact that `Sqrt[f^2]==f` is simply not true (take for example any non-positive `f`). That's why MMA does not simplify it automatically. Using `Assuming` or `Assumptions`, you can tell MMA that `f>0`, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 Assuming[f > 0, FullSimplify[Sqrt[f^2]]]
```

and the output is `f`. Since $\sqrt{f^2}=|f|$ you can either get $f$ or $-f$, so you have to assume something about $f$.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{f^2} = |f|$ for real values only.

Comment: Yes, since we assume $f>0$ it can't be a complex number.

Comment: Why is `Sqrt[f^2]` not defined for all (real) $f$?

Comment: @anderstood It is defined and equal to |f|.